# Is support for IVisitAggregationContext Interface removed in Sitecore 10 XP

Tags: xconnect

In Sitecore 8.2 we used to have a reference of `IVisitAggregationContext` interface in `AggregationPipelineArgs` class which we were using in the custom processor to grab visit-related data. But when I am trying to use the same in Sitecore 10 we are unable to do that. I have gone through the aggregation pipeline dll and there is no reference to the above interface in the processors available and also in the context object. I am using `InteractionAggregationPipelineProcessor` and `InteractionAggregationPipelineArgs` args in Sitecore 10 for grabbing those values. I am not sure whether I am using the correct processor or not.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by "grab visit-related data", but you probably want to look into creating your own FlexibleMetrics which will let you extend the aggregation system. Info is here: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/walkthrough--reporting-on-a-new-dimension.html

Comment: In 8.2 we use to have VisitData class which comprises of class members such as TrafficType,SiteName,Profiles Dictionary etc. As this VisitData class is member of  IVisitAggregationContext interface and as mentioned above the interface is not a part of InteractionAggregationPipelineProcessor  in Sitecore 10 i am unable to find how i can grab the VisitData information.

Comment: Right. As noted, in newer versions of Sitecore, the aggregation system has been redesigned. You won't be able to do a 1-for-1 replacement.